# Co-opting Binding to listen to PropertyChanged events without a FrameworkElement

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have some nested view models that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I'd like to bind an event listener to a nested property path (e.g. `"Parent.Child.Name"`), much like `FrameworkElement` dependency properties can be bound to arbitrary nested properties.

However, I just want something like a `PropertyChanged` event listener -- I don't actually have any UI element I'd like to bind. Is there any way to use the existing framework to set up such an event source? Ideally, I shouldn't need to modify my view model classes (as this is not required for regular data binding in Silverlight).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly co-opt the binding/dependency-property infrastructure to listen for changes to a nested property. The code below is WPF but I believe you can do something similar in Silverlight:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new Parent { Child = new Child { Name = "Bob" } };
        this.SetBinding(ChildNameProperty, new Binding("Child.Name"));
    }

    public string ChildName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ChildNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ChildNameProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ChildName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ChildName", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(ChildNameChanged));

    static void ChildNameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Child name is now " + e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

So I've defined my own `DependencyProperty`, not part of any UI per se (just the `MainWindow` class), and bound "Child.Name" to it directly. I'm then able to be notified when `Child.Name` changes.

Will that work for you?

Comment: That could work, but I'm hoping to do this without the overhead of an actual UI control, or being tied to the UI thread. How would I unsubscribe from notifications in this case when I no longer need them?

Comment: You shouldn't need a UI control - anything that derives from DependencyObject can define its own DependencyProperty. Unsubscribing should be as simple as SetBinding(ChildNameProperty, null).