# Communication between viewmodels piggybacking off of the iNotifyPropertyChanged system

Tags: mvvm, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I am using MVVM and I would like to communicate between viewmodels. I have a user control that contains another user control inside it, and I would like the parent usercontrol to run some code when a property in the child is changed. I have seen several ways to communicate between viewmodels, such as using MVVM Light Messenger, or PRISM Event Aggregator, but I was hoping there was some way to accomplish this simply by somehow subscribing to the `PropertyChanged` event raised through the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

There is an answer by Matt Hamilton in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882393/co-opting-binding-to-listen-to-propertychanged-events-without-a-frameworkelement) but I have trouble implementing it because it needs a DependencyObject, and my ViewModels are POCOs rather than DOs

Is there some way of using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` system, as I would prefer to not have to implement a messaging system. If not is a messaging system the best? I also saw an example where some guy just used the code behind of the view to help pass the property, however I don't want to break the MVVM pattern as I wanna do some testing at a later stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There definately multiple ways to handle your scenario.  One is certainly to use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation to propogate your event.  The issue is that container would need a direct reference to the child ViewModel to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event.

class ParentVM
    {
        private const string SomePropertyName = "SomeProperty";

```
    public ParentVM()
    {
        ChildVM child = new ChildVM();
        child.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(child_PropertyChanged);
    }

    void child_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == SomePropertyName)
        {
            //Do something!!!
        }

    }
}
```

You could also explicitly define an event and subscribe to it.

Comment: Ah great! so simple! Cant believe I didn't see this event in the Intellisense. Would have helped if I had been the one to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged, would have understood so much more. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would pass a reference of the parent viewmodel to each child viewmodel to have direct access.

I tend to avoid the MVVM Light "Messenger" as much as possible. (it's kind of useless when using IoC containers but that's another story)

Comment: Why is it useless for IoC? Is the workaround to just use GetInstance to ensure that all messages are received with valid listeners?

Comment: @SliverNinja I use an injected service like "IMessagingService" that essentially does the same thing as what the MVVM Light Messenger does.

Comment: @vidalsasoon Yea I thought about this, but I'm hesitant to change the constructors of all my usercontrols until I know that I cant simply use the INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @vidalsasoon Kerry H has a very simple solution, check it out above

Comment: @vidalsasoon I thought about it some more and another reason is because I don't want my child to have knowledge about the parent. The parent is creating the child (no dependency injection is used) so it seems that one way knowledge is less coupled than them both having references to each other. I want the children to stand alone so that they can be used in other forms without adaptation, and placing the parent in the constructor leads to all sorts of extra code each time the control is used by another form.